# Error message after account linking success

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, simulator, account-linking

I am getting an agent error after account linking success message.

After the user completes the account linking process, the agents says that he doesn't understand what the user is saying (but the user hasn't said a word!).

Here's how I start the account linking process:

```
if (accessToken) {
    conv.ask(loggedMessage)
  } else {
    conv.ask(new SignIn())
    conv.close(loggedMessage)
  }
  agent.add(conv)
```

The function finishes with a 200 status code, but I get an error on the simulator:

[image]

"Desculpe, mas não compreendi" is Portuguese for "I am sorry, but I did not understand".

Is this happening because the mic stays open when I use `conv.ask` ? How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share the error you get after linking the account?

Comment: Are you handeling the `Sign-in` event in your webhook? https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_helper.signin.html

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help! I edited the question to add these details. 

But yes, I am handling the Sign-in event in my webhook. The webhook does not yield an error. However, the agent says "I don't understand" right after finishing the account linking process - that is the problem.

Comment: Could you share the full error message you get? Also, regarding the print screen does it work with those examples?